# how to cut the filename in way to contain only the first word before separator

Tags: bash, awk, sed, rhel, perl

I am trying to get the  package name of the whl files

the files are

```
ls  /python/*.whl
/python/argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl                   /python/Jinja2-2.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
/python/certifi-2019.9.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl                /python/kazoo-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
/python/cffi-1.14.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl         /python/MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
/python/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl                    /python/protobuf-3.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

while expected output should be ( without `-..........whl` ) , as the following example

```
  ls  /python/*.whl | SOME SYNTAX ......

    /python/argparse      /python/Jinja2
    /python/certifi      /python/kazoo
    /python/cffi         /python/MarkupSafe
    /python/chardet     /python/protobuf
```

any ideas how to get only the package name as above?

Comment: yes I used sed , but cant resolved the issue about how to cut the "-" from the last file and stay on with pkg name

Comment: I dont think theta are useful because they not good examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, [don't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Instead, use globs:

```
$ for f in /python/*.whl; do printf '%s\n' "${f//-*}"; done
/python/argparse
/python/certifi
/python/cffi
/python/chardet
/python/Jinja2
/python/kazoo
/python/MarkupSafe
/python/protobuf
```

Note that this will remove everything after the first `-` in the path. So if you have a `-` before the package name, you might get wrong results.

Answer (score 4):

Two ways: Use a parameter substitution to delete the bit of the filenames after the first dash on an array containing the names, or on each name individually in a loop.

Using an array:

```
$ names=( /python/*-*.whl )
$ printf '%s\n' "${names[@]%%-*}"
/python/Jinja2
/python/MarkupSafe
/python/argparse
/python/certifi
/python/cffi
/python/chardet
/python/kazoo
/python/protobuf
```

Alternatively to use the positional parameters rather than a named array:

```
set -- /python/*-*.whl
printf '%s\n' "${@%%-*}"
```

Using a loop:

```
$ for name in /python/*-*.whl; do printf '%s\n' "${name%%-*}"; done
/python/Jinja2
/python/MarkupSafe
/python/argparse
/python/certifi
/python/cffi
/python/chardet
/python/kazoo
/python/protobuf
```

I'm using the pattern `/python/*-*.whl` to match the filenames rather than just `/python/*.whl`, just to make sure the names that we match actually contains a dash that we can use to trim the filenames.

The `${variable%%pattern}` parameter substitution is a standard substitution that removes the longest possible substring matching `pattern` from the value of `$variable`.  The `bash` shell allows the use of this substitution on the elements of arrays as well (which we use in the first variations above).

To get the same sort of columns as `ls` would produce, pipe the resulting names through `column`, e.g.,

```
$ for name in /python/*.whl; do printf '%s\n' "${name%%-*}"; done | column
/python/Jinja2           /python/certifi          /python/kazoo
/python/MarkupSafe       /python/cffi             /python/protobuf
/python/argparse         /python/chardet
```

Answer (score 1):

One way, no loop:

```
printf '%s\n' python/*.whl | cut -d'-' -f1
```

Answer (score 1):

command

```
ls /python/*.whl| awk -F "-" '{print $1}'
```

ouput

```
/python/Jinja2
/python/MarkupSafe
/python/argparse
/python/certifi
/python/cffi
/python/chardet
/python/kazoo
/python/protobuf
```

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
print -rC1 /python/*-*.whl(Ne['REPLY=${REPLY%%-*}'])
```

Or:

```
() { print -rC1 "${@%%-*}"; } /python/*-*.whl
```

Or:

```
set -o histsubstpattern
print -rC1 /python/*-*.whl(N:s/-*//)
```